# How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sin^{2}n}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sin^{2}n}{n}$?

*Mathematica* shows

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sin^{2}n}{n}=\frac{1}{4}\left(-\ln4+\ln(1+e^{-2i})+\ln(1+e^{2i})\right)$$

I wonder how to prove it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to expand $\ln(1+e^{2i})$ and   $\ln(1+e^{-2i})$ as Taylor series and add it. Then, use $e^{i\theta} +e^{-i\theta}=2\cos\theta$ (for $\theta=2n$).

Comment: Don't end up with a "complex-like" looking result. You must have finally a purely real answer...

Answer (score 6):

Just apply $\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n}$ for $\lvert x\rvert\leq 1$, $x\neq 1$.  Remember $\sin n=(e^{in}-e^{-in})/(2i)$.

Comment: ... or, slightly less complicated $\sin n=Im(e^{in})$. In both cases, you must find back geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

We want to evaluate 
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\sin^2{n}}{n}.$$
Firstly, by the reduction formula for $\sin$, we write 
\begin{align}S &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\left(1-\cos{n}\right)}{n}\\[20pt]
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cos{n}}{n}.\end{align}
The series on the right hand side is $=-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)$ [can be computed by power series for $\log(1+x)$]. Now let's deal with the series on the right hand side. Define
$$\mathcal{W} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cos{n}}{n}$$
so that 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{W} = \Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n e^{in}}{n}\right)
\end{align}
By 
\begin{align}
-\log(1+x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^n}{n}, \\[20pt]
-\log(1+e^i) & = \mathcal{W} = \Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ne^{in}}{n}\right)
\end{align}
But we want the real part of the left side. So,
\begin{align}
&-\Re\left(\log(1+e^i\right) \\[20pt]
&= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\log\left(\sin^2(1) + \left(\cos(1)+1\right)^2\right)\right)\end{align}
Substituting everything into the latter expression we have that 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\sin^2{n}}{n} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\log(2) + \log\left(\sin^2(1) + \left(\cos(1)+1\right)^2\right)\right).
\end{equation}
I know this post was made a while ago, but for anyone who may still be curious, I hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the expression 
$\ln(1+t)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^n}n$ below

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sin^{2}n}{n}
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(\frac{e^{in}-e^{-in}}{2i}\right)^2\\
=&\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(-{e^{2in}-e^{-2in}+2}\right)\\
 =& \frac14 \left[\ln(1+e^{2i})+ \ln(1+e^{-2i})-2\ln(1+1)\right]\\
=&\frac14 \ln \frac{(e^i+e^{-i})(e^{-i}+e^{i })}{4}\\
=& \frac14 \ln \cos^2(1)=\frac12 \ln \cos(1)
\end{align}